# Java - Excluding Child Dependency in Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gson

I have two project that names are payment-orchestrator and payment-connector.

payment-orchestrator is included payment-connector as maven dependency as shown below;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>${version.gson}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.payment</groupId>
    <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

payment-orchestrator has a gson library and also payment-connector contains an external jar that names integrator.jar but this jar use different versioned gson library. In this case, I am getting an error during calling JsonParser.parseString method like this

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement;
```

I think, I have to exclude second gson library that exist in integrator.jar but couldn't because this library is in the jar. This code block doesn't work properly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>${version.gson}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.payment</groupId>
    <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

How can I handle this situation? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290023/how-to-exclude-nested-dependency-in-maven

Comment: Are the classes of the other older Gson version bundles in the "integrator.java" (i.e. a "JAR with dependencies")? If so, are you the author of "integrator.java" or can you contact the owner and ask them to _not_ bundle classes of other JARs (such as Gson) inside of it? Or create two variants, one "JAR with dependencies" and another regular Maven artifact without dependency classes included. Otherwise you might have to manually remove the Gson classes from that JAR.

Comment: @Marcono1234 yes, I am not the author of this jar but will contact the owner. Thank you.